# Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I recently updated my studio to Arctic Fox and got an error in my project

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, 
is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven3(http://dl.bintray.com/mobisystech/maven)' to redirect to a 
secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. 
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
```

Answer (score 7):

Check your repositories in your **build.gradle**. Ideally they should point to an **https** domain.

Example.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

If url only exists under http protocol, you can add **allowInsecureProtocol** property. See following example

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true //add this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. I tried "setAllowInsecureProtocol(true)", too. Gradle 7 does not build with our company internal repository. :/

Comment: Any solution for this. I am also facing the same with version 7

Comment: My problem got solved by adding `allowInsecureProtocol = true` in my (Windows) C:\Users\<userid>\.gradle\init.gradle file for Gradle-v7

Comment: @TheDeepThinker I can't find the file where is it ??

Comment: i think you must at inside of buildscript and not at allprojects @TheincredibleJan

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after adding allowInsecureProtocol = true into maven repository defined in C:\Users<userid>.gradle\init.gradle file.